# Javascript auto-update condition value

Tags: javascript

Let's set:

```
i = 1;
condition = i < 2; // Users makes this condition, not me.
```

condition value is **true**;

Now a little change.

```
i = 3;
```

And condition value will keep **true**;

Since I "don't know" the *condition*, is there a way I can re-check the value of the condition?

I need something to make condition value become **false** right after setting i = 3;
What I have to do with the variable 'condition' to make it **false**, but remember: I don't know the "condition" (i < 2), because users will make it, not me.

Comment: Could you explain what you are speaking of? I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Users makes this condition"?  Is the condition being specified in a string?  Like anything else, to get a realtime logical condition, you should be using a function.

Comment: This question makes perfect sense to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

condition must be a function to be evaluated each time.

you can do things like :

```
var i = 1;
var condition = function() { i < 2 };
if(condition()) {
   alert('ok');
}
i=3;
if(!condition()) {
   alert('ok');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to reevaluate and reasign the condition variable. I would do it like this:

```
function evaluate(i, condition){
    evaluation = i < condition;
    return evaluation;
}
i=3;
condition = 2;
conditionMet = evaluate(i, condition);
```

Now, every time you want to reevaluate, you just call `evaluate()`.

Comment: Users makes the condition, not me.